# convert Epoch to js date object/moment date object in react js excluding timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

We store the Unix epoch time in database which is in number format. Ex: **1528137000** is **5 June 2018 00:00:00**.

**Note**: not interested in time

**5 June 2018** should always be displayed irrespective of timezones.

Currently using

```
const epochValue = 1528137000;
console.log(moment.unix(epochValue));
```

Executing above code in **Kolkata location** will output as `moment("2018-06-05T00:00:00.000")`

Executing above code in **Toronto location** will output as `moment("2018-06-04T14:30:00.000")`

But I always need the output as **2018-06-05** ie., June 5, 2018 this object will be binded to DatePicker material design control.

Comment: convert date to timezone as `UTC`

Comment: can you give some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your database is in **Kolkata location**

Store/compute your epoch in UTC referential :

Epoch `1528137000` is `5 June 2018 00:00:00` at Asia/Kolkata (IST)

But `5 June 2018 00:00:00` is epoch `1528156800` in UTC :

```
const epochValue = 1528156800;
alert(moment.unix(epochValue).utc());
```

If you can't, change the time from Asia/Kolkata (IST), +05:30 to UTC time :

```
const epochValue = 1528137000 ; // your date at midnight,  Asia/Kolkata (IST)
alert(moment.unix(epochValue).add(+5.5,'h').utc());
```

Comment: database is in cloud in US location

Comment: how to convert **2018/06/05** to utc epoch which should be **1528156800**.. having some tough time

Comment: moment('2018-06-05T00:00:00+0000').unix() ==> 1528156800